# отправка "письма с картинкой" java

Tags: java, javamail

я уверен, что подобные вопросы тут задавались, но что-то не нашёл. 
нужно отправить письмо с картинкой в теле письма. так же хорошо б чтобы она не попадала в категорию вложения, а просто следовала в содержании, как часть html страницы.

вот код, он работает почти полностью, только саму картинку в полученном письме не отображает.. например в Thunderbird. (ошибок чтения файла при чтении DataSource нет)

собственно вопрос в том, почему не отображается картинка в письме на клиенте? это в коде что-то или почтовый клиент такой, что ему нельзя отправить картинку, чтобы он её отображал?

```
        try {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(galkovStates.FROM));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            msg.setSubject(MAIL_TITUL, galkovStates.ENCODING);

            // Create your new message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String htmlText = "<a href='https://...'><img src='cid:asd'></a>";

            // Create a related multi-part to combine the parts
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


            // Create part for the image
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Fetch the image and associate to part
            DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(file);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<asd>");

            // Add part to multi-part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Associate multi-part with message
            msg.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(msg);

        } catch (MessagingException e) {    e.printStackTrace();    }
```

Comment: в догонку. дело в том что в почту всё время валится спам, у которого картинки моментально открываются в теле письма и нет раздела "вложения". 
собственно хотелось бы тоже самое получить, только в мирных целях .. :)

Comment: Размещайте картинку на своем (или чужом) сервере и вставляйте в html с помощью специального тега

Comment: считает, что так разумнее?   String htmlText = "<a href='https://...'><img src='...'></a>";
мне кажется такая конструкция ещё более подозрительна для базовых настроек безопасности.

Comment: замените  messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<asd>"); на messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример

```
    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    message.setFrom(from);
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
    message.setSubject(subject);

    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

    helper.setText(body, true);
    helper.addInline(attachmentName, attachmentInputStream, attachmentContentType);
    mailSender.send(message);
```

В теле письма добавить `<img src="cid:picture.png"/>`. `picture.png` это `attachmentName`.

`mailSender` это `org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender`.